# Python OpenCV not detecting obvious contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Apologies as I'm very new to OpenCV and the world of image processing in general.

I'm using OpenCV in Python to detect contours/boxes in this image.

[image: Original]

It almost manages to detect all contours, but for some odd reason it doesn't pick up the last row and column which are obvious contours. This image shows the bounding boxes for contours it manages to identify.

[image]

Not entirely sure why it's not able to easily pick up the remaining contours. I've researched similar questions but haven't found a suitable answer.

Here's my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load image
img = cv2.imread(path)

#remove noise
img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)

#convert to gray scale
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#make pixels darker
_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
        
#thresholding the image to a binary image
thresh, img_bin = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#inverting the image 
img_bin = 255 - img_bin

# countcol(width) of kernel as 100th of total width
kernel_len = np.array(img).shape[1]//100

# Defining a vertical kernel to detect all vertical lines of image 
ver_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_len))

# Defining a horizontal kernel to detect all horizontal lines of image
hor_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_len, 1))

# A kernel of 2x2
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))

#Use vertical kernel to detect and save the vertical lines in a jpg
image_1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, ver_kernel, iterations = 3)
vertical_lines = cv2.dilate(image_1, np.ones((10, 4),np.uint8), iterations = 30)
vertical_lines = cv2.erode(vertical_lines, np.ones((10, 4),np.uint8), iterations = 29)

#Use horizontal kernel to detect and save the horizontal lines in a jpg
image_2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, np.ones((1, 5),np.uint8), iterations = 5)
horizontal_lines = cv2.dilate(image_2, np.ones((2, 40),np.uint8), iterations = 20)
horizontal_lines = cv2.erode(horizontal_lines, np.ones((2, 39),np.uint8), iterations = 19)

# Combine horizontal and vertical lines in a new third image, with both having same weight.
img_vh = cv2.addWeighted(vertical_lines, 0.5, horizontal_lines, 0.5, 0.0)
rows, cols = img_vh.shape

#shift image so the enhanced lines overlap with original image
M = np.float32([[1,0,-30],[0,1,-21]])
img_vh = cv2.warpAffine(img_vh ,M,(cols,rows))

#Eroding and thesholding the image
img_vh = cv2.erode(~img_vh, kernel, iterations = 2)
thresh, img_vh = cv2.threshold(img_vh, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

bitxor = cv2.bitwise_xor(img, img_vh)
bitnot = cv2.bitwise_not(bitxor)

#find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_vh, cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create list empty list to append with contours less than a specified area
new_contours = []

for contour in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 4000000:
        new_contours.append(contour)

#get bounding boxes
bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(contour) for contour in new_contours]

#plot detected bounding boxes
img_og = cv2.imread(path)
for bounding_box in bounding_boxes:
    x,y,w,h = bounding_box
    img_plot = cv2.rectangle(img_og, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0) , 2)

    plotting = plt.imshow(img_plot, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the deal with `#shift image so the enhanced lines overlap with original image`? I would assume at that point you are already in trouble. Did your excessive amount of dilations and erosions drift away out of the image dimensions?

Comment: Have you looked at your thresholded image? Otsu thresholding may be losing the black lines for that row.

Comment: @ypnos Great question. I should have provided a little more background info. I'm working with various images that look identical though vary in overall image quality. Some that are considerably bad have "gaps" in vertical and horizontal lines which makes finding contours difficult. Dilating lines as I have fills in gaps, but shifts the lines slightly and they don't align with the original, hence why I added the portion to shift the image.

Comment: @fmw42 Great suggestion. So I ran a version of my code that doesn't apply thresholding to the image and while it managed to capture other contours this time (very tiny areas in the image), it still did not manage to identify the ones mentioned in my OP.

Comment: Have you tried deskewing your image before detecting your horizontal and vertical lines?

Comment: @fmw42 Funny you should ask. I'm starting to believe that's the problem. The code I shared is just of portion of my program which includes code to deskew the image. I've noticed that, at times, the resulting "deskewed" image is not 100% deskewed as evident by the images I posted. It rotated the image slightly using IrfanView and applied my code to it and the results were better, but not perfect. I need to find a way to remove 100% of the skew and I believe it will successfully find all contours. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick. The have a deskew function based upon the radon transformation. See https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.1/ and https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#deskew. Alternately, do Hough line transform and get the angle of the lines. Then rotate your image. You can also search Google and find a number of links to Python/OpenCV solutions.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks so much. I'll check these out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [@ypnos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21974/ypnos) was suggesting, the dilation and erosion has most likely pushed the last line off the image in the "saving horizontal lines" section. So the `image_vh` wouldn't have the last row when it was being searched for contours. I tested (Note:1) this by viewing the image after each of your transformations.

Specifically, the number of iterations had been too much. You had used a reasonably sized kernel as it is. It gave perfect results with `iterations = 2` on lines 43 and 44 of your code.

After modifying them to :

```
horizontal_lines = cv2.dilate(image_2, np.ones((2, 40), np.uint8), iterations=2)
horizontal_lines = cv2.erode(horizontal_lines, np.ones((2, 39), np.uint8), iterations=2)
```

the bounding box rectangles had shifted off the image a bit. That was fixed by changing line 51 of the code to:

```
M = np.float32([[1, 0, -30], [0, 1, -5]])
```

This was the result. [image: Image with bounding rectangles]

Note:

1. I test/debug using this function usually.

> ```
> def test(image, title):
>     cv2.imshow(title, image)
>     cv2.waitKey(0)
>     cv2.destroyWindow(title)
> ```

The variable position and the handy waitkey calms me down.

Comment: Turns out it was the erosion! I followed your steps and modified it a tad more and it's finally finding all the contours I wanted. The reason I had excessive iterations is because I'm working with several identical images but of varying quality. Some have very poorly defined lines and so it seems I need excessive iterations to fill in gaps. My new problem is that the kernel is dependent on the quality of an image which varies--is there something I can do so that the kernel adjusts based on the quality of an image?